# Ingress nginx path routing

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I have a React application deployed on AKS and the URL to the application landing page is https://myapp.host.com/dev/

Currently the application have multiple screens to navigate for example: /profile

When I click the profile navigation button, it redirects to this url: https://myapp.host.com/profile which is not what I want. Although the profile page is able to load, however if the page is refreshed it will return error as the application is not able to read the https://myapp.host.com/profile URL. By right, I want it to be https://myapp.host.com/dev/profile so that even if the page is refreshed, the app will able to load.

Here is my Ingress configuration:

```
ingress:
  name: myapp-ingress
  annotations: 
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
  hosts: 
  - host: myapp.host.com
    paths: 
    - path: /dev/(.*)
      pathType: Prefix
      backend: 
        service:
          name: myapp-svc
          port: 
            number: 8080
  tls: 
  - hosts: 
    - myapp.host.com
    secretName: myapp-ingress-tls-secret
```

What should I change in my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also a newbee for ingress, but maybe it's because that

according the ingress-nginx doc,
`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` means that Target URI where the traffic must be redirected.

so
`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1` means when you matched `/dev/profile` it will redirect to `/profile`
so maybe you can remove it and try again?